# Manage nuumber of connections for OCserv and FreeRADIUS

Tags: linux, freeradius

I have numbers of Ocserv servers and connected to a FreeRADIUS server for authentication. I have configured directive bellow in Ocserv of each server to don't let a user connect more than 2 times.
 `max-same-clients = 2`
but it works in server itself and a user can connect 2 times to each server.
I want my clients to connect only 2 times and if a user is active 2 times in server 1, there will be no more connection for that user in the rest of the servers.
is there any way to manage this issue?